# How do I display my data from counter list as a graph?

Tags: python

I have a program which counts the occurrence of each number and adds it to my counter. I have used collections counter. When printing my counter I receive the data that is stored.

```
Counter({1856: 109, 1331: 4, 1351: 3, 1341: 2, 1376: 2, 1371: 2, 1356: 1, 1361: 1, 1396: 1})
```

My program ends with displaying this data but I also want to display it as a graph. Any ideas?

This Payload was Discovered at the Following Start Offsets:

```
The Start Offset: 1856 was Discovered a Total of 109 Times!

The Start Offset: 1331 was Discovered a Total of 4 Times!

The Start Offset: 1351 was Discovered a Total of 3 Times!

The Start Offset: 1341 was Discovered a Total of 2 Times!

The Start Offset: 1376 was Discovered a Total of 2 Times!

The Start Offset: 1371 was Discovered a Total of 2 Times!

The Start Offset: 1356 was Discovered a Total of 1 Times!

The Start Offset: 1361 was Discovered a Total of 1 Times!

The Start Offset: 1396 was Discovered a Total of 1 Times!
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of options but one popular choice is [`matplotlib`](https://matplotlib.org/).

Here is a simple bar chart using `matplotlib.pyplot`

```
from collections import Counter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

c = Counter({1856: 109, 1331: 4, 1351: 3, 1341: 2, 1376: 2, 1371: 2, 1356: 1, 1361: 1, 1396: 1})
plt.bar([str(key)  for key in c], c.values())
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much I've spent so long trying to get this to work haha